# RestAssured customize TLS version

Tags: java, testing, rest-assured

Currently RestAssured's only way to force a TLS version when making a request is to use a deprecated class (`SslSocketFactory`), and setting the `SSLConfig` to use a `SslSocketFactory` initialized with a `SSLContext` set to some TLS version.

Is there another way to do this with RestAssured, or are there any other java testing frameworks that would allow for this customization?